# How to work with the Web Designer?

Tags: css

I am a programmer, and I would like to outsource the design work to the designer to do all the designing jobs, but I don't want to give them the compete source code. But giving only the view, they can't simulate what is the situation going on.

Please give some suggestions on how to work with the designer.

Comment: surely the designer should be the one sending the view to *you*? generally the designer does the art then we translate it to code. Other than that I can't give you any kind of answer as your question is quite vague

Comment: I make a simple output to the designer, let say I only have the a field, or some output text. That's why I need a designer to help me.

Comment: Please explain your situation more in detail. Normal web development starts with a graphic template or layout, or just a basic schema of where the elements should be placed, then the coder will setup the html structure and then make it work with scripts if needed.

Comment: I developed my application using some kinds of php framework, after I develop, I find that I need somme designers to do make up for my application.

Comment: @Ted Wong - So you basically need a css coder?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a password protected site where the designer can work with it to see how everything works. You probably already have a simple site to work with while developing.